# Android Overlaying images in layer-list

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I am trying to create a custom drawable which includes a 9-patch background image (named custom_bg below) and a regular png image (accordion_up). The latter should not be scaled.

I tried several variations of something along the lines of:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_bg"/>
    <item
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/accordion_up"
        android:gravity="right" />

</layer-list>
```

Tried different values for `layout_width`/`layout_height` and also `width`/`height` but all I get is the accordion image is stretched to fill the entire view. I would like it to float at the top right of the view instead, scaled only to match the dpi of the device, but not expanded to fit the view. How can I do that?